# Large JSON array data passing as a parameter is coming null in Java servlet POST

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

I wrote an Ajax request from Ext js to Java servlet and passed a jsonarray as a parameter. It is coming as null when I pass large json array, however it is working for small jsonarray. Is there any way to set maximum size for jsonarray in java or in extjs?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                url : 'ExecuteServlet',
                method : 'POST',
                async : false,
                params : {
                    jsonArrData:jsonArrData,
                    container_code:container_code,
                    module_id:module_id,
                    extraction_id:extraction_id,
                    transformation_ids:transformation_ids,
                    loading_ids:loading_ids
                    },
                success : function(result, request) {
                }
});
```

Comment: What is a "large json array"? A few million / billion entries? A few GB big or just a couple MB?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look in the network inspector?

Comment: Yes, I checked the network inspector and it is passing all the data from client side, but in servlet the data is coming as null. I guess, I have to do some json compression at the client side before passing the parameter. It is happening in case of large amount of data only, for small scale data it is working without any issues.

Comment: Well I think it you will have to take a look in the logfile of the server if everything is passed. Maybe there is a limitation in your server.

Try to create some dummy data about the size of your json and test it with an service like https://designer.mocky.io/ or http://www.jsontest.com/